# How to specify wild card paths while reading a file in U-SQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am using below code to read a file from Azure data lake store (ADLS Gen1)using U-SQL

```
DECLARE @InputFile string = 2021/2021-Mar/*/{*}.json";    
@json =
EXTRACT
col1 int?,
col2 string    
 FROM @InputFile
USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor("data[*]");
```

The 2021 folder has data for different months and I want to read data from all months from March-October (except Jan and Feb). I was looking for a regular expression for the same.
**I have used the below one, but didn't work**

```
2021//{2021-Mar,2021-Apr,2021-May,2021-Jun,2021-Jul,2021-Aug,2021-Sep,2021-Oct/}/*/{*}.json"
```

Comment: There is a double quote missing from your DECLARE statement. Try this: ```DECLARE @InputFile string = "2021/2021-Mar/{*}.json";```

Answer (score 0):

A double quote is missing from the DECLARE statement in your code. Also, you need to remove the extra `*` before `{*}` and it should work. Find the example below:

`DECLARE @InputFile string = "2021/2021-Mar/{*}.json";`

Comment: I have given double quotes when tested, my question was specifically on how to mention all months except January and February of 2021 , ie months from March-October